# Multiplication of leptonic - hadronic tensor

Tags: scattering, tensor-calculus, scattering-cross-section

I am about to proof

$$ L_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}=8\Big(2(k \cdot p)(k' \cdot p) + \frac{q^2}{2 M^2} \Big). $$

from leptonic tensor:

$$ L_{\mu\nu} = 2(k'_\mu k_\nu + k'_\nu k_\mu + \frac{1}{2}q^2g_{\mu\nu}) ,$$

and hadronic tensor

$$T^{\mu\nu}=(p+p')^\mu(p+p')^\nu,$$

I have tried to expand the $T^{\mu\nu}$

$$T^{\mu\nu}=(p^\mu p^\nu + p^\mu p'^\nu + p'^\mu p^\mu + p'^\mu p'^\nu),$$

but then I can't get the pattern. Here, we use framework of rest particle target, e.g. $p^\mu=(M,\textbf{0})$, the final hadron $p=(E',\textbf{p'})$, with lepton initial $k=(\omega,\textbf{k})$ and final $k'=(\omega',\textbf{k}')$.